# woocommerce order received page display error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce "Order Received" page displays "gtag" code between payment details and order details. Attached screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq3dr.jpg)

Where do I remove it?

I have looked through all the theme child files including:
templates/checkout/thankyou.php
templates/order/order-details.php

Comment: Woocommerce is not adding the gtag conversion.  Something else is.

Comment: As Howard said, it's either from a plugin or a custom theme.
You can see what active theme files are custom loaded under "WP Admin -> Woocommerce -> Status -> Templates -> Overrides"

Comment: Thanks, turned out to be "Custom" setting that was enabled in Woocommerce Settings | Tracking.  Disabled and resolved.